# NancyFX: How do I check if query-string / form values have been correctly passed to my handler?

Tags: dynamic-language-runtime, nancy

Nancy passes my query-string and form values to my handlers via a `dynamic` variable. The example below shows form values being passed in to a POST handler via the Nancy request e.g. `Request.Form.xxx`.

**Handler**

```
Post["/"] = _ =>
    {
        var userId = (string) Request.Form.userid;
        if (userId.IsEmpty()) return HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;
        return HttpStatusCode.OK;
    };
```

You can see that I am casting the `userid` to a string and then using a string extension method to check if the value is null or empty string (equivalent to `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`).

What I would prefer is to to have the extension method on the dynamic type so I could perform my sanity checks before doing anything else. I want code like this:

```
if(Request.Form.userid.IsEmpty()) return HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;
```

However, you cannot have extension methods for `dynamic` types. Also, you cannot check for the presence of a property via reflection. Welcome to the DLR.

**Question**

What is the easiest, safest way to perform pre-checks to ensure that the expected query/form values have been passed to my Nancy handler?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Request.Form.userid.HasValue
```

Works for all DynamicDictionary members, such as Form, Query and route parameters

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bind i.e a ModelBinder to Bind your model to the form, where the properties of the model class corresponds to your HTML control names.

```
var course = this.Bind<Course>(); // Course is our model class 
if(course != null) {
    // your codes go here
}
```