# Routing in NancyFX

Tags: nancy

A sample route in Nancy can be like:

Get["/method/key1={value1}/key2={value2}"]

which can be reached by calling it as:

/method/key1=foo/key2=bar

I want to write the querystring in below manner:

method?key1=value1&key2=value2

What would be the route for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be the following route:

```cs
GET["/method"] => x
{
   var key1 = Request.Query.key1;
   var key2 = Request.Query.key2;
};
```

Where **Query** is [DynamicDictionary](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Taking-a-look-at-the-DynamicDictionary).

Related Questions:

- > [Get url parameters in NancyFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189172/get-url-parameters-in-nancyfx)
- > [Why are no query parameters being passed to my NancyFX module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302891/why-are-no-query-parameters-being-passed-to-my-nancyfx-module)
- > [NancyFX: How do I check if query-string / form values have been correctly passed to my handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512727/nancyfx-how-do-i-check-if-query-string-form-values-have-been-correctly-passed)